# When to load settings table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a web app, using asp.net MVC Core, along with entity framework core. Part of this application has a simple setup table. This is just a table, which will only ever have one record, with a number of fields in, so the administrator can easily change how the web app works.

The setup table is loaded into a static "Settings" class, so anywhere in the application can read it (views and controllers)

What I want to know is when or how is the best place to load this. At the moment I'm loading it in Startup.Configure, after the routes have been set.

For the most part, this works fine. But if I add a field to the setup table, its impossible to migrate (I'm using code first). I get errors about invalid fields. Typically the errors look like this:

```
An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: One or more errors occurred. (Invalid column name 'EmailApiKey'.
Invalid column name 'EmailBaseUrl'.
Invalid column name 'EmailSenderAddress'.
Invalid column name 'EmailSenderDomain'.
Invalid column name 'EmailSenderName'.)
Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>' to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns supported at design time.
```

To get around this, I have to remove the code thats loading the setup table.

This makes me think this is not the best place/way to load settings (seeing as though it obstructs with database migrations).

So - is there a better way to do this? Essentially, I want to:

- load a setup table once when app first started.
- Have this accessable everywhere in the application (views and controllers).
- If a user changes the setup, the static version should be automatically updated.

Comment: A static property is not good practice. Consider using `MemoryCache`. And a database table with a single row does not really make sense. Consider a xml file or similar to store the data.

Comment: This is a design issue. As mentioned already  the choice of object model is not very flexible. Consider using key-value pairs for the settings object model and table. next store them in a cache to limit loading from data store. when setting is update, expire the cache and reload it with the updated settings.

Comment: The settings need to be easily changed by the end user (who wont necessarily be that tech savy), so an xml file is not that appropriate.

And I realise a single record is not that flexible - but it doesnt need to be.

Comment: An xml file has nothing to do with a user changing the data! (its just a storage mechanism, as a database is). You have a class defining properties with values and you read/write to a file just as you read/write to a database

Comment: OK. So rather than save to the database, I can seralise the setup object to xml (or json, or whatever), and save it somewhere? But where do I save this to? Is there a standard place that the app can read/write to, but the user cant (so not in the wwwroot).

Answer (score 0):

I would lazy-load the settings on first access rather than at application startup.  An advantage is that if the lazy-load fails, you'll just try again next time it's accessed.

> If a user changes the setup, the static version should be automatically updated.

You could cache it in the ASP.NET Cache or `MemoryCache`.  You can set an expiration so that it will be refreshed periodically in case a user has made changes.  Or if the settings are in a SQL Server database, you can use [the SqlCacheDependency class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx).

Comment: I considered lazy loading, but that would mean getting a reference to the ApplicationDbContext in a static object, and I wasnt sure how to do this (I'm using the Entity Framdwork).

As far as the automatic updating goes, at the moment when the user modifies the setup table, I just update the static objects version (in the save code). So something like that would work.

Comment: Are you able to give me a bit more information on how/where I would lazy load it?

Comment: @Shaggs, you could load it into a static field, or in a cache.  In either case, you simply do a null test when accessing it, and load it if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. So, the constructor of the controllers is a good place to do this? I'm trying this now, and it seems to be working. I've put the code in the constructor of almost all the controllers.